# Convert json column content key value pairs to separated key value

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-json, json-extract

My table looks like this:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {tags: {"env": "dev", "owner": "me"}} |

I want to fetch the data and inside the select query convert the data column to the following format:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {tags: [{"key": "env", "value": "dev"}, {"key": "owner", "value": "me"}]} |

I've tried several JSON mysql functions but the closest I got is :

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {tags: [{"key": "env", "value": ["dev", "me"]}, {"key": "owner", "value": ["dev", "me"]}]} |

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: WHY? Look perfectly usable as it is now

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, JSON_OBJECT("tags", JSON_ARRAY( JSON_OBJECT("key", "env", "value", JSON_EXTRACT(json_column, "$.tags.env")), JSON_OBJECT("key", "owner", "value", JSON_EXTRACT(json_column, "$.tags.owner")) )) as data FROM table_name
```

**JSON_EXTRACT** : extract the values of the "env" and "owner" keys from the json_column
**JSON_OBJECT** : create two JSON objects with the "key" and "value" keys and the extracted values
**JSON_ARRAY** : create a JSON array of these two objects
and finally wraps the array in another **JSON_OBJECT** with the "tags" key.

Comment: Thanks!
The only problem with your solution is that the keys are dynamic, I don't want to implicitly refer to specific key but have a generic extraction that loops on all tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic approach which will also work on `data` fields that have multiple top-level keys and multiple second-level keys:

```sql
select t1.id, (select json_objectagg(t1.k1, 
    (select json_arrayagg(json_object('key', t2.k2, 
         'value', json_extract(t.data, concat('$.', t1.k1, '.', t2.k2)))) 
       from json_table(json_keys(json_extract(t.data, concat('$.', t1.k1))), '$[*]' columns (k2 text path '$')) t2)) 
  from json_table(json_keys(t.data), '$[*]' columns (k1 text path '$')) t1) 
from tbl t;
```